# Why do I keep getting this error when going from ViewController to TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have this button in my viewController and when I press on it, it should go to the TableViewController. When I do this the app crashes and prints this error in the console. Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong? Thank you!

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>       reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with 
>       identifier "UIViewController-iLh-Fe-Ezq" from storyboard "Main", but didn't 
>       get a UITableView.'

Comment: the top-level object in the scene must be a tableview. My guess is that you have a tableview inside a UIview

Comment: This problem may occurs when your view controller in storyboard is UITableViewController but your custom class for that view controller is not, and vice versa.

Comment: So do I have to make a table view controller without the view controller?

Comment: Im trying to make a table view but I need to add a bar button item, how do I do that? Its not letting me put it above the prototype cell.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When I got this error, I had initially used the boilerplate code for the *class* **UITableViewController**, but the *actual view controller* was a **UIViewController**.

**Original code (resulting in the error)**:

Note that this is connected to a *UIViewController* in Storyboard.

```
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {
//insert rest of code here 
//note that funcs such as numberOfRowsInSection(_:) will have the override keyword 
}
```

**Working code (removing the error)**:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
//insert code here 
//you also must *remove the override keywords* for
// some of the included functions or you will get errors
}
```

*Remember also to reference an IBOutlet for your UITableView in your view controller, and set the delegate and datasource (in Storyboard, you Ctrl+Drag from the UITableView to the yellow circle at the top of the view controller, and click dataSource. Repeat this for the delegate as well).*

Comment: what do you meant by "click dataSource" after drag a component segue line to that yellow circle?

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha apologies but I wrote this half a year ago so I actually cannot remember what I was referring to. It is likely that I meant that "dataSource" was one of the options in the menu that pops up after Ctrl+Dragging, however.

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha, it seems when ctrl-dragging from UITableView to the yellow circle like David said, you get a menu with the choices datasource & delegate. Pick one & then ctrl-drag again to pick the other as well. In addition to taking out the "overrides" from func certain funcs, I also changed the class definition to "class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { ... }". Thx for solution, David.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, was exactly my set up, completely forgot that my view was a UIViewController..

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work....I used a table view controller without the view controller and embedded a navigation controller.